# Utility class for functions

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to improve overall performance of a javascript application and i'm trying to create a utility class for all independent functions. Is it a good practice to do that?

Also i have read that is ok to use anonymous functions like this:

```
(function(){

 var Utils = {
    test: function () { ... },
    test1: function () { ... }
    ...
 }

}())
```

But for some reason i am unable to use Utils.test() inside my other class, i get

```
ReferenceError: Utils is not defined
```

and now i am using

```
  var Utils = {
   test: function () { ... },
   test1: function () { ... },
   ....
  }
```

will there be any improvements by doing so or should i just stick to classic separated functions

```
function test() { ... }
function test1() { ... }
....
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: You've created an IIFE, and any variables defined inside that IIFE is only accessible in that scope.

Comment: instead of `Utils = ` do `window.Utils =` (browser only) ...

Comment: *"I'm trying to improve overall performance of a javascript application"* Putting all your utility functions on an object (it's not a class) won't improve the *performance* of your app. But it's still a good idea, because the global namespace is *really crowded*, so using a single symbol you then look up your functions on reduces the odds of conflict with something else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need different syntax to work with an IIFE, but I believe it is good practise to do so

```
var Utils = (function(){

 return {
    test: function () { ... },
    test1: function () { ... }
    ...
 }

}())
```

Comment: Great, thank you! I will accept your answer as soon as i can :)

Comment: @Simon how it is different from the approach mentioned in the question. will it improve performance? can you explain?

Comment: Thank you. I was refactoring my utils functions so that I can easily test them through mocha/chai and I believe that your method is suitable for my needs :). Here is my code befor refactoring https://gist.github.com/sangimed/f04a0e92135ba5ec43d8c63f3221e904

Answer (score 6):

For a reasonably-sized project usually you'll have a project namespace under which all the project code falls so you don't unnecessarily pollute the global namespace. You can pass in the namespace as an argument to the IIFE and attach the code you create within it to the namespace. Something like this:

```
;(function(namespace) {

  namespace.Utils = {
    test: function() {
      console.log('test');
    },
    test1: function() {
      console.log('test1');
    }
  };

}(this.namespace = this.namespace || {}));

namespace.Utils.test(); // test
```

Answer (score 1):

Today with ES6 you would probably export all methods in the root of a module and then do `import * as Utils from 'utils.js'`

Answer (score -1):

Gualtiero Testa [wrote about this on his blog](https://gualtierotesta.wordpress.com/2013/06/25/utility-functions-in-javascript/). I think that this approch is better if you're on a ES6 env.

> The usual approach I adopt (and suggest) is to create an utility class
>   like the following one:

```
function Util () {}

Util.read = function (sel) {
    return jQuery(sel).val();
};

Util.write = function (sel, val) {
    jQuery(sel).val(val);
};
```

> How to use the utility functions ?

```
// read the value of the element with id myinput
var val = Util.read('#myinput');
```

Comment: What is the reason of declaring `Utils` as function when one is never going to use it but just wants to assign some utility methods to it?

Comment: @PeterSeliger `function Util () {}` is a class definition (done by creating an empty constructo). Thenk the actual util methods are hooked to this class.

Comment: Of course, that's obvious. But what is the intention of using a class that is never going to be instantiated as utility namespace.